# selenium WebDriverError: connection refused nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, geckodriver

node version: v8.5.0 
npm version: 5.3.0 
geckodriver: v0.19.0 
"selenium-webdriver": "^3.5.0" 
 
I'm trying to test selenium webdriver in nodejs, however I keep getting the following error:

```
/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2634
            throw error;
            ^

    WebDriverError: connection refused
        at Object.throwDecodedError (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:497:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
        at Function.createSession (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
        at Function.createSession (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:572:41)
        at createDriver (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
        at Builder.build (/home/app_path/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:645:16)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app_path/app.js:20:2)
        at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
```

A Mozilla firefox window just opens, and after some time, this error appears in console. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('firefox')
.build().then(function(){
    console.log("log");
    driver.get("https://google.co.in");
});
```

how to fix this?

**EDIT** Here's the stacktrace

> {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"connection refused","stacktrace":"stack backtrace:\n   0:           0x4f388c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h736111741fa0878e\n   1:           0x4f38c2 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h63b8a5c0787510c9\n   2:           0x442d88 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hea6d4dbf778b2b24\n   3:           0x449f99 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hf8b6061dba65cdd0\n   4:           0x42ac91 - >::run::hba9181b5aacf8f04\n   5:           0x402c59 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h19de262639927233\n   6:           0x40c065 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h6c1659fc4d01af51\n   7:           0x5e38ec - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic\n                        at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98\n   8:           0x420d32 - >::call_box::h953e5f59694972c5\n   9:           0x5dc00b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>\n                        at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:661\n                         - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread\n                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21\n                         - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start\n                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84"}}

Comment: Firefox version? Hope it is the latest one?

Comment: geckodriver will use  a random and idle port when running, check your turn off fireware or config right iptable to allow port traffice,  if they are configure right, try differenr geckodriver

Comment: @yong i believe it works fine because a new firefox window opens up when running this, and when i manually type any address instead of using driver.get(), that works fine too.

Comment: you type address manually only prove the website work fine.  seems v0.19.0 is the latest version so far. it can work fine with my firefox 55,  if your firefox is lower than 55, you can try lower version of geckodrvier.

Comment: @yong Thanks for the advice! I manage to resolve this issue by using geckodrvier v1.8.0 for my Firefox ESR (v52)